# fork() in C program

Tags: c, pthreads, fork

This is a question from recent GATE entrance exam.
A process executes the code

```
fork();  
fork();  
fork();
```

The total number of **child** processes created is

> (A) 3. (B) 4. (C) 7. (D) 8.

My answer was **(A) 3.**

My view is that after each fork(), 1 child process will be created and execution of parent will continue normally.

Unreliable answer (without any explanation) from coaching institutes were **(C) 7.**

I think they are treating that each fork will create a child process and a new parent process. And they are counting all the parent process as well. *[I am not allowed to post image but my friend explained in a diagram, a tree with each left node forking down in two nodes. Therefore 4 parent node in left and 3 child node in right.]*
But the Question clearly mentions child process only. And also I don't think that parent process is newly created in forking.

Can someone explain some forking fundamentals, and a proper solution to above question please.

P.S. If programming language make any difference in concept of forking, then as per syllabus, this should be either C or C++ program.

Comment: The child processes created by the first process go on to `fork()` themselves. You should count those too.

Comment: No, forking is an OS concept - the programming language won't matter.

Comment: This shows why multi-choice questions are diabolical for demonstrating understanding.  If you had to write an answer that explained how you arrived at the answer, you could get credit for understanding the concepts even if you came to a different conclusion from the 'official answer'.  For example, are the children of the child processes to be counted?  It changes the answer to be given.

Comment: Actually, a really good question would be: Justify each of the answers (a) 3, (b) 4, (c) 7, and (d) 8.

Comment: @Rup so as an OS concept, would forking on windows and unix be different??

Comment: Windows doesn't (AFAIK) have an exact equivalent of fork(). Rather than forking, on Windows you'd create new worker threads inside the same process instead. The other use of fork on linux (or vfork) is to create a new process in which you immediately exec() a different executable; on Windows you just CreateProcess specifying the other executable to do this. (That all said, Windows does have a POSIX layer for SUA, so it must support fork at some level - but it's rarely ever used.)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`fork()` results in both the original process and one child to start **from that point in the code**. Therefore you have this picture:

[image]

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Hehe thanks, and nice job on your answer, after all it is more detailed!

Comment: @eznme"-from that point in code-" does this means that after second fork the child and parent both will continue executing from next line which is the third fork() statement?

Comment: @AbhinavKulshreshtha hmm, think of it this way: `fork(); fork(); fork();` there is one process in the beginning, there are 2 processes executing the first semicolon, there are 4 processes executing the second semicolon, there are 8 processes executing the third semicolon. (then subtract 1 because you only want child-processes)

Answer (score 16):

I think there are 8 processes in total, or 7 descendents of the original, or 3 direct children of the original (the others are grand-children and great-grand-children).

- After the first `fork()`, assuming no failures (throughout), there are two processes.
- Each of those executes `fork()` again - so there are now four processes.
- Each of those executes `fork()` again - so there are now eight processes.

Comment: Official answer key from iit came out few days ago. The Correct answer is 7. unfortunately, they didn't gave complete solution set, just answers.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
printf("initial pid: %d\n", (int)getpid());
fork();
fork();
fork();
printf("final pid: %d\n", (int)getpid());
```

Comment: i got linker error for _getpid and _fork.  
This is the code i used 
`#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
void main()
{
  printf("Initial     pid: %d\n", (int)getpid());
  fork();
  fork();
  fork();
  getch();
}`

Comment: i am using turbo c++ 3.1 under dosbox emulation, in windows 7

Comment: Neither DOS nor Windows have `fork()`. You cannot try that snippet in those Operating Systems. I have no idea how to do the same in DOS; you can try [CreateProcess()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v%3Dvs.85%29.aspx) in Windows (which is not exactly like `fork()`).

Comment: No, DOS can only run one process at once so it has no equivalent. If you want to try this your best bet is probably to get VMware player or similar and set up a Linux VM, or find a unix machine somewhere on the internet that you can get a shell account on.

Comment: Or buy a Raspberry Pi for €40. it's a complete Linux machine with a 700MHz ARM SoC. Completely enough to test this kind of things.

Answer (score 3):

After each call to fork there are two processes, the parent and the child.  And *both* of those processes continue executing immediately after the fork.  Some of the resulting processes are (after all of the forking) both parents and children.  The ones that are *only* children are the *leaves* of the process tree.  The one (the original one) that is *only* a parent is the *root* of the tree.  The ones that are both parents and children are the *branches*.

Comment: so in the diagram above, children are the 8 leaves at the bottom, and root node is the parent. the answer should be 8.

Comment: @AbhinavKulshreshtha: In the diagram above the leftmost vertical line is the original process and is *not* a child created by any of the `fork()` in the example.  It *is* a child of some other process but I would not have counted it as created by `fork(); fork(); fork()`

Comment: Official answer came out to be 7. They did not provide full solution but on this page, yours explanation along with @eznme diagram is the simplest. thanks

Answer (score 3):

At the end of the third fork call, there will be a total of 8 processes. Out of these 8 processes, there will be 7 child processes and 1 parent process.

There are two important points to note while solving these type of problems:

1. A fork() call returns twice, once in the parent and once in the child process. If fork is successful, it returns with a value of 0 in child process and with non-zero value(pid of child) in parent process.
2. Both the child and parent process starts executing right after the fork call.

I have explained the above problem with the help of a diagram and also a video. I hope you find it useful.

[image: fork example gate]

[fork example](https://youtu.be/iZa2vm7A6mw)

Answer (score 0):

A generalized formula can be used for this type of questions,

Total number of processes will be 2^n.

Formula for getting total number of child processes created is (2^n) - 1, where n is number of times fork function is called.

Here fork() is called 3 times so number of child processes will be (2^3) - 1 = 7.
There are total 7 child processes and 1 parent process.